# Weird white box in jQuery autocomplete menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-autocomplete

So I have this weird problem/issue with my autocomplete styling in CSS. If you look at the following images below, you can find that there is this weird "white block" or "space" that just seems to be in the middle of all the results.

[image]

[image]

**CSS:**

```
body .ui-autocomplete {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   border: 0px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -336px;
   display: none;
   outline: none;
   z-index: 1000;
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-corner-all {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 14px;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   outline-color: none;
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-focus {
   background: none !important;
   background-color: none !important;
   border: 0px !important;
}
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `background-color` property in `body .ui-autocomplete`. See example.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
body .ui-autocomplete {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -336px;
  display: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-corner-all {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  outline-color: none;
}
body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-focus {
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: I must have not caught that tiny little detail. Thanks lots!